# Spring websockets and group messages

Tags: spring-websocket

I would like to implement a chat using Spring websockets. What will be the best way to implement groups?

- Register a new `UserDestinationMessageHandler` for URLs like `/group/{groupname}/queue/*` and create a new `UserDestinationResolver`. Are there any examples for this?
- Make the controller implement `ApplicationListener<SessionConnectedEvent>`. But how can I get the session attributes from the event?

In both options I was taking into account that I will register the group to which the user belongs into session attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a destination like "/topic/group/{name}/message" managed by message broker and have user subscribed to it.
To send a message you can either send it to the same destination or you can send it to a destination like "/app/message" and have it forward it from there. The latter option has the advantage that you can filter the message.